# Connect external client to Docker websocket

Tags: python, docker, websocket

I created a Flask python application that makes use of `socketio` and it is running on `0.0.0.0:5000`. When I run it locally, I have a separate Python client that uses `socketio` to try to connect to the `localhost:5000` and sends messages to the WebSocket connection. The messages show on a web page, etc..

The Issue:
When I wrap the Flask application in a Docker container I can bring it up and see the web page. I am using `docker run -it --rm -p 5000:5000 myapp:latest`  to run this container.
When I try to run the `client.py`, which is outside the container, to connect to the container that has the Flask WebSocket connection running I get a "Connection Refused by the server" error.  I am using: `httP://localhost:5000` in the external client to try to connect to the Docker container.

How can I connect to a WebSocket server in a Container from an external python client?

Docker File:

```html
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

EXPOSE 5000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN  apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y netcat

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "application:app"]
```

Flask Application:

```html
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, copy_current_request_context
from random import random
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abcd!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

#turn the flask app into a socketio app
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=None, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@socketio.on('timseriespoint', namespace='/test')
def to_chart_display(msg):
    socketio.emit('tochart', {'number': msg.get('number')}, namespace='/test')
    #socketio.sleep(5)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    #only by sending this page first will the client be connected to the socketio instance
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Client (outside Container):

```html
import socketio 
import time
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # standard Python
    sio = socketio.Client()
    sio.connect('http://0.0.0.0:5000', namespaces=['/test'])


    i=0
    while True:
        i+=1
        random_number = random.uniform(-100, 100)
        sio.emit('timseriespoint', {'number': random_number}, namespace='/test')
        time.sleep(1)

        if i > 50:
            break

    sio.disconnect()
```

Comment: The error seems to suggest your application inside the container either not listening to `0.0.0.0` or the port `5000`. Double check the Flask logs.

Comment: Added the code to the description - to show the configuration of the connections.

Comment: Can you try directly sending request to your docker container. Get the container IP and then use `curl http://<docker-ip>:5000`

Comment: I did ran the Flask application container, then did "docker ps", then "docker inspect id", and under "Networks" tried both the Gateway and IPAddress.  I still got a connection refused error.

Comment: @zd5151 I've reproduced the example and it works for me without modification. So maybe you have to check with a very basic example your docker setup is OK?

Comment: @zd5151 this means your application is not listening to `0.0.0.0` or port 5000. You can do this: docker run -it -net container:<flask container id> bash` and then run `netstat -ntlp` (you need to install that with `apt install ...` first). Then check if your app is listening to the correct `host:port`

Answer (score 1):

I think that your general approach of `docker run -it --rm -p 5000:5000 myapp:latest`is okay.

I just wonder how your docker networks are configured.
Are you using a bridge in docker network?

If not: create a bridge: https://docs.docker.com/network/ should provide information

Is your application really listening on `0.0.0.0` inside of the container and not on `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: No, I'm not using a bridge. I've uploaded the code to show the configuration of the connections.

Answer (score -1):

I've reproduced your example and it works, even if it seems to timeout after a certain time.

### Reproducing the problem

1. Launch the server container

```sh
# launching the server (named flask)
$ docker run -dit --rm -p 5000:5000 --name flask flask 

# [2020-11-06 07:55:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
# [2020-11-06 07:55:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
# [2020-11-06 07:55:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
# [2020-11-06 07:55:04 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
# Server initialized for threading.
```

2. Connect to it from outside (the host)

Logs displayed are from inside the container. I've just added a log in the server code to display received message `print(f"Received message -> {msg}")`.

```sh
# launching the client
$ python client.py

$ docker logs -f flask  

# 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07', 'upgrades': [], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
# 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
# 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/test
# Client connected
# 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0/test
# 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07: Received packet PING data None
# 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07: Sending packet PONG data None
# 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07: Received packet MESSAGE data 2/test,["timseriespoint",{"number":-13.160625972337428}]
# received event "timseriespoint" from 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07 [/test]
# emitting event "tochart" to all [/test]
# 0e2aceeafa664700ae2f6f9892b7ca07: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2/test,["tochart",{"number":-13.160625972337428}]
# Received message -> {'number': -13.160625972337428}
```

3. Connection refused

If I try to let the container run and launch the client again, I observe a connection refused.
At this time I guess the problem seems to not be more related to the framework you are using Flask-SocketIO than to Docker.

```sh
$ python client.py

# Traceback (most recent call last):
# ...
# socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by the server
```

### Debug

You can try to inspect the default bridge to see if the container uses it.

```sh
$ docker network inspect bridge

# "Containers": {
#      "71451e0d82b578f63baa36b6e8fc1e33a9f4ca29f9c3460394723042fe3cf490": {
#          "Name": "flask",
#          "EndpointID": "320744772e66b28075949d81c1976a616eff278406a2027135e4542fb5f3e140",
#          "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
#          "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
#          "IPv6Address": ""
#      }
#  },
#  "Options": {
#      "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
#      "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
#      "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
```